# I'm trying to append to append to a specific index in a 2D list

Tags: python-3.x

```
a=1+2 
import csv
    all_items=[]
    with open('stockes.csv') as product:
        stockes=csv.reader(product)
        for row in stockes:
            all_items.append(row)
    print(all_items[1][2])
    all_items([1],[2]).append(a)
```

sorry but the a is in place of my normal variable this is also my first question

Comment: `all_items([1],[2]).append(a)` ??? I bet your error is `object all_items is not callable`. What is your question BTW?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. It's not clear why you thought that syntax would work.

Answer (score 0):

the list is
[['bar code', 'names', 'stock', 'prise'], ['13245627', 'plain brackets', '3', '599'], ['12345670', '100 mm bolts', '7', '550'], ['56756777', 'L-shaped brackets', '8', '230']]

```
a=1+2 
import csv
    all_items=[]
    with open('stockes.csv') as product:
        stockes=csv.reader(product)
        for row in stockes:
            all_items.append(row)
    print(all_items[1][2])
    all_items([1][2]).append(a)
```

sorry I hope this is better